# I need a DeepFreeze work around

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

The library i frequent has added the windows program deepfreeze and now I can't run Ubuntu Persistent Live from my USB stick, is there a work around?

Comment: Since the library's use of `deepfreeze` indicates that they don't want you to do this, doing so anyway could get you in Administrative/Legal trouble with the library. Don't.